# Inconsistent timing in node red with trigger node set to resent interval

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, node-modules, node-red

**Program function**

A few sensors updating at a set interval via a trigger node that sends a true value every second.

**What happens**

Sensors update 4-5 times with the correct delay. Then the delay time is doubled then goes back to normal. *repeat*

**What I tried**

I thought that multiple requests were eating up cpu clocks and increased my clock speed to double disabling a the scale down function so a consistant clock speed is maintained. But this did not work does any one have any insight to this?

*My input flow with my sensors taking continuous readings*
[image: Input flow]

*My test flow that triggers relays at intervals so I can visually and audibly hear the timing. With all flows disabled except this flow the timing is on but with any other flows enabled the timing gets off.* 
[image: Resend test flow with relays]

Comment: Do you mean an inject node when you say trigger? Also are you using just one inject linked to all the sensor nodes? It might be worth including a copy of your flow or at least a screenshot so we can see how you've put things together

Comment: I updated with flow pictures and a description.